# Weird postfix logs

Tags: server, mail, postfix, logs

At the mail.log this appears ~2 times per minute. I didn't care what they were, but now I want to find the reason.

```
Oct  2 20:27:02 sa-pd postfix/cleanup[31255]: 13A342CE301C: message-id=<20121002182702.13A342CE301C@sa-pd.eu>
Oct  2 20:27:02 sa-pd postfix/bounce[30816]: E41782CE301B: sender non-delivery notification: 13A342CE301C
Oct  2 20:27:02 sa-pd postfix/qmgr[6230]: 13A342CE301C: from=<>, size=2454, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 20:27:02 sa-pd postfix/qmgr[6230]: E41782CE301B: removed
Oct  2 20:27:02 sa-pd postfix/virtual[27222]: 13A342CE301C: to=<www-data@sapd@CENSORED(itsmymaindomain)>, relay=virtual, delay=0.18, delays=0.09/0/0/0.09, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "www-data@sapd@CENSORED(itsmymaindomain)")
Oct  2 20:27:02 sa-pd postfix/qmgr[6230]: 13A342CE301C: removed
Oct  2 20:28:02 sa-pd postfix/pickup[24018]: 18D432CE301B: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Oct  2 20:28:02 sa-pd postfix/cleanup[31255]: 18D432CE301B: message-id=<20121002182802.18D432CE301B@CENSORED(itsmymaindomain)>
Oct  2 20:28:02 sa-pd postfix/qmgr[6230]: 18D432CE301B: from=<www-data@sapd@CENSORED(itsmymaindomain)>, size=657, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 20:28:02 sa-pd postfix/virtual[30817]: 18D432CE301B: to=<www-data@sapd@CENSORED(itsmymaindomain)>, orig_to=<www-data>, relay=virtual, delay=0.33, delays=0.26/0/0/0.07, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "www-data@sapd@CENSORED(itsmymaindomain)")
```

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some program running as the `www-data` user that's sending an email every minute. If it's indeed trying to send email to `www-data@sapd@somewhere.example.com`, the email address is ill-formed, presumably mistyped in some configuration file. Look for that address somewhere in your configuration files (try `grep -r www-data@sapd@ /etc ~www-data/`).